# Is there a way to link the unversioned directory created by svn export to its branch in SVN?

Tags: svn, merge, export, branch

I have a copy of the contents of an svn branch locally without any .svn folders. The equivalent of the output of an svn export of that branch. I'd like to link up this directory to its corresponding branch in version control, without having to do an svn checkout followed by manually merging my changes in.  Is there some way to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in SVN, but I've been using it for a few years and have never seen a way to do this. I'd just do it manually.